# Vector field where curl of the field is the field itself

Tags: calculus, vectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I was curious if there is a possibility of a field where the curl of the field would be the field itself, i.e, $$\nabla \times \vec{A} = \vec{A}$$

I can immediately see that the divergence of such a field is $0$ so it may be written as $\vec{A} = \nabla \times \vec{B}$. This is also sort of equivalent to find the eigenvector of the anti symmetric matrix $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{\partial}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0 & -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
    -\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$As this is normal, I think eigenvectors should exist.I am asking this because I am curious to see how a field whose rotation at every point is the field itself would look like except the zero vector field.

Comment: Consider the zero vector field.

Comment: @BenSteffan I have modified the question and excluded the trivial case

Comment: Related: [What are the Eigenvectors of the curl operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186201/856) I'm not sure if an eigenfunction with eigenvalue 1 exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenfunctions of the curl operator, i.e. $\nabla\times \mathbf B=k\mathbf B$ for eigenvalue $k$, are studied in physics as examples of [force-free magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-free_magnetic_field). [Kirk T. MacDonald's notes](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/forcefree.pdf) list many solutions. One of the simplest is Lundquist's solution, which in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z)$ is given by

> $$
> B_\rho = 0, \quad B_\phi = J_1(k\rho), \quad B_z = J_0(k\rho)
> $$
>   where $J_0$ and $J_1$ are Bessel functions. The field lines are helices, and since the Bessel functions are oscillatory in $\rho$ there are both left- and righthanded helices, and ones with both positive and negative $B_z$.

Comment: In the paper mentioned, the simplest solution is (cos z, -sin z, 0).