# Eigenvalue of Hermitian operator(curl) complex?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

This question is in continuation to a previous question [What are the Eigenvectors of the curl operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186201/what-are-the-eigenvectors-of-the-curl-operator). I know now that the curl operator \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{\partial}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0 & -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
    -\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}is hermitian(http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/curlherm.html). This should mean that the eigenvalues of this operator should be purely real. We can check this as $\vec{B} = (cos\ z, -sin\ z, 0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. However, $\vec{B} = e^y(1, 0, -i)$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue -i. What am I missing here?